# Android10 Platform : NoClassDefFoundError on invoking Aidl library API

Tags: jenkins, linker, runtimeexception, android-10.0, aidl

We have a class named as **X** , It has reference to aidl library **LibA** from class **Y**. There is one more class named **Z**, where we have an  java sdk aidl library **LibB** inside Class **Z**.

Class **X** is trying to call a method from **LibA** **testMethod(ObjectB)**

**ObjectB** is a Parcelable object from **LibB**

We are facing  NoClassDefFoundError  for ObjectB when calling testMethod from Class X

How to resolve this runtime issue in Android 10 platform.

We are using Android bp file convention to build the files in Jenkins platform

***ClassX***

android_app {

```
name: "ClassX",
srcs: [
"aidl/**/*.aidl", 
"java/**/*.java",
],
libs: [ClassY.LibA],
required: []
```

}

***ClassZ => LibB***

java_sdk_library {
name: "LibB",
manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",
srcs: [
"java/**/*.java",
"aidl/**/*.aidl",
],
aidl: {
local_include_dirs: ["aidl"],
},
api_packages: [
"LibB",
],
compile_dex: true,
}

***ClassY => LibA***

java_sdk_library {
name: "LibA",
manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",
srcs: [
"java/**/*.java",
"aidl/**/I*.aidl",
],
aidl: {
local_include_dirs: ["aidl"],
include_dirs: ["LibB/src/main/aidl"],
},
static_libs: [ "androidx.annotation_annotation"],
libs: ["LibB"],
api_packages: ["LibA"],
}
***ClassY***
android_app {
name: "ClassY",
srcs: ["aidl/**/*.aidl", "java/**/*.java"],
libs: ["LibB", "LibA"],
required: ["LibB"]
}

Comment: The Problem is very likely in your build system. On android it is very likely gradle.
In order to help you further you should post your gradle dependency configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but build system is pointed to Android.bp file & we are using Jenkins to build the source file.

Comment: Have provided the required permission to that lib? (a XML file under etc/permission)?